Save manifest with parameter type="dynamic"
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd"
     profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash-if-simple" 
     type="dynamic" 
     availabilityStartTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" 
     publishTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" 
     minimumUpdatePeriod="PT30S" 
     minBufferTime="PT2S" 
     timeShiftBufferDepth="PT1M" 
     maxSegmentDuration="PT2S">

I tried everything I had
-init_seg_name "init-$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
-media_seg_name "sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$" 
-dash_segment_type webm 
-use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 9 
-adaptation_sets "id=0, streams=v id=1, streams=a" 
-live 1 
-chunk_start_index 1 
-time_shift_buffer_depth 60 
-f dash {pathfilm}manifest.mpd

When converting a file, in the manifest
type="dynamic"

When video conversion is finished
type="statick"

The question is how to force ffmpeg. When the video conversion is complete, save the manifest with the parameter
type="dynamic"

??

What operating system?

You can't. It's hardcoded to write static when manifest is done.
